# How do I solve the UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter blurry text problem

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, blur

If I set a UITextField to UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter, the placeholdertext is kind of blurry. Any suggestion?

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: use a nice cotton rag to clean the screen :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is UITextField but it's the same issue:

[UITextField blurred text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254657/uitextfield-blurred-text)

Comment: Yeah - same thing happens in Flash too

Comment: That's not a bug.  When you draw anything that lies between pixels, it will appear blurry because it is not properly aligned.  You just have to make sure that you align your views to integer pixel bonudaries.

Comment: Yeah Flash was the worst for this... if there was blur, you knew straight away it's because your item was on a strange x or y axis like 20.2. So you fix by re-aligning and then it appears again at 20.7 :-)