# Why does UIImageview show a blurry image?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios4, uiimageview

I am testing my app in two devices. One iOS 4.3, and the other has iOS 5. The app is built in ios 4.3. Why do images look blurry when I run in iOS?

Do I need to take any extra care when apps run on iOS 5?

Comment: how big is the image? where is the image being loaded from (internet, filesystem, attached to the app, etc)

Comment: Please provide more details ...

Comment: use imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; then it'll work fine...

Comment: Try to check the image ratio.

Comment: I think @Shubhank is on the right track. Are the two devices the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be facing an issue of anti-aliasing that is applied when a view's frame are fractional (particularly the origin, the rest are adjusted accordingly). Use `CGRectIntegral` to recalculate your UIImageView frame.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254657/uitextfield-blurred-text) is a similar question (not of UIImages) but the reason seems very much similar.

Answer (score 0):

This can be explained if one device is of standard resolution (320 x 480 ) and other is a retina model.. since the same image will be stretched to twice the size in the retina model..it will appear to be blurred..solution is to increase the image size..wherever it is situated..to twice its current resolution

Answer (score -1):

The new iphone 4 and 4s has retina display whose resolution is 640x960 twice the resolution of  previous iphones .So if you have image of lower resolution like 320x480 when its opened in iphone 4s with double resolution the image got blurred.