# CGRectIntegral what is the usage of it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

How does one use the CGRectIntegral function? I understand it's purpose.

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html) isn't clear on it's exact use.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

**CGRectIntegral to convert any decimal values to their integer equivalents** 
see image may be you can understand [image]

How do I fix it?

```
frame = CGRectIntegral(frame);
```

-OR-

```
myTextView.frame = CGRectIntegral(myTextView.frame);
```

see this [for more information  of CGRectIntegral](http://iosdevelopertip.blogspot.in/2014/10/cgrectintegral.html)

Comment: The image on the left is a little fuzzy because the frame is set on a pixel boundary. So the origin is something like 20.5, 8.5. CGRectIntegral snaps it back to 20, 8.

Comment: If you want blurry images to be highlighted in purple in the iOS simulator, choose Debug > Color Misaligned images. That way, you won't have to squint all over the place to figure out which things are blurry.

Comment: It's important to add: CGRectIntegral is for filling/drawing pixel buffers. Stroked shapes are centered around their coordinates, so you may actually need non-integral (e.g. 0.5 on 1x screens) coordinates to make them appear crisp. See here for a more detailed explanation: http://orangejuiceliberationfront.com/are-your-rectangles-blurry-pale-and-have-rounded-corners/

Answer (score 15):

`CGRectIntegral` Method is used to create integer rect . I mean to say suppose if you calculate frame in app you may get frames value in float.

Setting float value as frame to some UIElement like `UILabel` would make the text looks blur. To avoid that, we use  `CGRectIntegral`.Please look at the example below,

```
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(   CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 15.6, 16.1, 20.2))));
```

This will print, {0,15},{17,21}.

This explanation is found in the header file.

```
/* Expand `rect' to the smallest rect containing it with integral origin and
   size. */
```

Answer (score 8):

One particular usage is to fix frames that do not align perfectly with on-screen pixels.

See this question: [UITextField blurred text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254657/uitextfield-blurred-text/1254660#1254660)

If a label or textfield has a frame that isn't pixel-aligned when rendered to the screen, the text will appear blurred. This can happen if you calculate the frame using division (for example to center it in a parent view).

`CGRectIntegral` will remove the fractional part of the frame, fixing this problem. Note however that with retina displays a .5 frame value is pixel aligned, but CGRectIntgral will still remove the fractional part.