# renderInContext: producing an image with blurry text

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am prerendering a composited image with a couple different UIImageViews and UILabels to speed up scrolling in a large tableview. Unfortunately, the main UILabel is looking a little blurry compared to other UILabels on the same view.

The black letters "PLoS ONE" are in a UILabel, and they look much blurrier than the words "Medical" or "Medicine".  The logo "PLoS one" is probably similarly being blurred, but it's not as noticeable as the crisp text.
The entire magazine cover is a single UIImage assigned to a UIButton.

[image: PLoS ONE label is blurry than "Medical Special" and "Medicine (Gener)"]
<sub>(source: [karlbecker.com](http://karlbecker.com/screen_blurry.png))</sub>

This is the code I'm using to draw the image. The magazineView is a rectangle that's 125 x 151 pixels.
I have tried different scaling qualities, but that has not changed anything.  And it shouldn't, since the scaling shouldn't be different at all.  The UIButton I'm assigning this image to is the exact same size as the magazineView.

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(magazineView.bounds.size, NO, 0.0);
    [magazineView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    [coverImage release];
    coverImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    [coverImage retain];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Any ideas why it's blurry?

When I begin an image context and render into it right away, is the rendering happening on an even pixel, or do I need to manually set where that render is occurring?

Comment: 125 by 151 pixels, or points? If it's the latter, what if you build for Retina and view it pixel-for-pixel in the Simulator? Do you find the text actually blurry, or pixel-doubled?

Comment: I've noticed that the simulator doesn't render text with perfect edges, but it turns out nice on the phone itself.  I don't know if that's your case or not though.

Comment: @Peter: Thanks for the correction - it's 125 by 151 points, since I'm getting that from the view's frame property.
[Retina display from Simulator](http://karlbecker.com/screen_blurry_retina.png)
It looks really good on the Simulator in Retina (note that the artwork is not yet upgraded for Retina)

Inturbidus: Same on device and in simulator, at least for regular iPad. The Retina text looks much, much better... can't explain the difference.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code that creates, sets up, and adds the label.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? We're seeing the same problem in our app (using integer values for the size / rect). We're drawing a UITextLabel into an image for caching purposes, but on Retina displays it's all fuzzy, like the image has been scaled up (I think it has). If we double the dimensions, the text is too small.

Comment: Turns out you need to use UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, YES, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale); in order to support both retina and non-retina displays.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that your label coordinates are integer values. If they are not whole numbers they will appear blurry.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use CGRectIntegral  for more information please see:   [What is the usage of CGRectIntegral?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9975374/1126111) and  [Reference of CGRectIntegral](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

---

I came across the same problem today where my content got pixelated when I am producing an image from UILabel text.

We use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions()` to configure the drawing environment for rendering into a bitmap which accepts three parameters:

> `size`: The size of the new bitmap context. This represents the size of the image returned by the UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext function.
>
> `opaque`: A Boolean flag indicating whether the bitmap is opaque. If the opaque parameter is YES, the alpha channel is ignored and the bitmap is treated as fully opaque.
>
> `scale`: The scale factor to apply to the bitmap. If you specify a value of 0.0, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.

So we should use a proper scale factor with respect to the device display (1x, 2x, 3x) to fix this issue.

Swift 5 version:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, true, UIScreen.main.scale)
if let currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() {
    nameLabel.layer.render(in: currentContext)
    let nameImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    return nameImage
}
```