# setting frame size of a button : decimal point values

Tags: iphone, ios, frame

it will In iOS Can I set frame size of a button as

```
btn1.frame = CGRectMake(20.5, 113.5, 92.5, 93);
btn2.frame = CGRectMake(113.0, 113.5, 186, 93);
```

Whether the decimal value will set or round?

For me, in 4 inch simulator display the buttons are coming proper without any gap between these two.
But in 3.5 inch simulator dispaly it coming with a gap between the two buttons. Why?

Comment: :btn.frame = CGRectMake(20.5f, 113.5f, 92.5f, 93.0f);

Comment: @Dev - Any one answer didn't help you ?

Comment: No Vakul Saini ... I dont know why it happening like this.. In $ inch display it is coming proper... but in 3.5 inch screen a small gap is coming.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CGRect` has `CGPoint` and `CGSize` which are all derived from `CGFloat` which is derived from `float`.

It can hold `float` value to all `CGRect` `cordinates` and will not `round`

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify whether a number has a decimal value by stating `f` at the end of decimal numbers.

This says that the number has a decimal part.

And, for your code, this should work:

```
btn1.frame = CGRectMake(20.5f, 113.5f, 92.5f, 93);
btn2.frame = CGRectMake(113.0f, 113.5f, 186, 93);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can give float value to button's frame.

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(20.5, 113.5, 92.5, 93.0);
```

And use `CGRectIntegral` to convert any decimal values to their integer equivalents.

After assigning frame to your buttons just write this -

```
button1.frame = CGRectIntegral(button1.frame);
button2.frame = CGRectIntegral(button2.frame);
```

You can see the effect before and after `NSLog` the `button` frame.
Example:-

```
button.frame = CGRectMake(20.5, 113.5, 92.5, 93.0);
NSLog(@"Before - %@",NSStringFromCGRect(button.frame));

button.frame = CGRectIntegral(button.frame);
NSLog(@"After - %@",NSStringFromCGRect(button.frame));
```

For more detail see this - [Apple doc on CGRectIntegral](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/1456348-cgrectintegral) and  [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9975374/1140335)

Comment: The above link is dead.

Comment: Hi, It's very old answer so may be link is dead but I also mentioned the detail in my answer. You can search more about 'CGRectIntegral' on Google.