# Pixel Gap Between CGRect

Tags: ios, swift

I'm drawing bar graphs, and I have several stacked CGRects that are directly on top of each other (i.e. one rect's minY is the previous rect's maxY). However, there are still semi-transparent gaps between the rects. Is there any way to fix this? I've found that this also happens when drawing touching adjacent arcs.

Here's a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

By zooming in, I've confirmed that this isn't just an optical illusion like one would find between adjacent red and blue rects. I would appreciate any input.

```
 var upToNowSegmentTotal: CGFloat = 0    
 for k in 0..<data[i].bars[j].segments.count {
      var segmentRect: CGRect = CGRect()

      if barDirection == "vertical" {
          let a: CGFloat = translateY(upToNowSegmentTotal)
          let b: CGFloat = translateY(upToNowSegmentTotal + data[i].bars[j].segments[k].length)
          upToNowSegmentTotal += data[i].bars[j].segments[k].length

          var rectY: CGFloat

          if a > b {
              rectY = b
          } else {
              rectY = a
          }

          segmentRect = CGRect(
              x: barWidthPosition,
              y: rectY,
              width: barWidthAbsolute,
              height: abs(a - b)
          )
      }
 }
```

Ignore the stuff about the width of the bars. Here's the translateY function. Basically, it translates coordinates from the graphing window into x/y stuff that's drawn. Remember that because the window/ graphing area does not change between drawn rects, the same y input will always produce the same result.

```
private func translateY(y: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    if barsAreReversed {
        return graphingArea.minY + graphingArea.height * (y - graphingWindow.startValue) / (graphingWindow.length)
    } else {
        return graphingArea.maxY - graphingArea.height * (y - graphingWindow.startValue) / (graphingWindow.length)
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

Here's a simplified version of my code that shows the problem:

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let rect1: CGRect = CGRect(
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 40,
        height: 33.7
    )
    let rect2: CGRect = CGRect(
        x: 0,
        y: rect1.height,
        width: 40,
        height: 33.5
    )

    let context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor(red: 1 / 255, green: 29 / 255, blue: 29 / 255, alpha: 1).CGColor)
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect1)
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect1)

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor(red: 9 / 255, green: 47 / 255, blue: 46 / 255, alpha: 1).CGColor)
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect2)
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect2)
}
```

It produces this:

[image]

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9975219/cgrectintegral-what-is-the-usage-of-it.

Comment: Could it be that at 100% opacity, each CGRect completely overwrites whatever is underneath it, even if it has some transparent parts that should be blended?

Comment: The code would probably be too much to show, since I have a bunch of complex functions. I'll add the most relevant parts though.

Comment: I'll do a simpler version now.

Answer (score 5):

I suspect that in this particular case, the rects you are filling are not integral, i.e they might have origins/heights that are by default rendered with slightly transparent pixels (anti-aliasing). You could avoid this by properly rounding your Y-axis translation

```
private func translateY(y: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    if barsAreReversed {
        return round(graphingArea.minY + graphingArea.height * (y - graphingWindow.startValue) / (graphingWindow.length))
    } else {
        return round(graphingArea.maxY - graphingArea.height * (y - graphingWindow.startValue) / (graphingWindow.length))
    }
}
```

With arcs and other shapes it is not as easy, however, you could try and get rid of it, by leaving a bit of overlap between shapes. Of course, as pointed out by matt, you could simply turn anti-aliasing off, in which case these transparent "half-pixels" will all be rendered as if they are actually fully-within the rect.

Comment: Surely on pixel-perfect edges, the system does not by default create a fuzzy edge that shows the background? Here's a playground to show you that this is not the case - https://www.dropbox.com/s/7r5tj1x6qscic0x/Aliasing.playground.zip?dl=0

Notice that neither of the drawings is anti-aliased, the borders are pixel perfect.

Comment: You didn't have to change anything else, because you masked the problem by not allowing the system to draw "to the best of its abilities" in terms of matching the rect that it was given.

Comment: @matt: If you change the height of the first rect to 33.0 (or even 33.5 on a Retina device) then I can observe no antialiasing at the boundary and no "gap".

Comment: Okay, that's convincing, I withdraw my previous comment.

Comment: @HenriNormak: One probably can improve the result by taking the devices scale factor into account (e.g. round to multiples of 0.5 on Retina devices). – But note also that the view itself might be scaled in its superview, so one might need to convert to device/window coordinates first.

Comment: Technically, yes you could achieve something that is "more accurate", however, whether that's worth the potential edge-cases and the code you would later need to maintain is a whole other topic :)

Comment: @HenriNormak: But the position of the view on the device windows *does matter*. It does not help if you round the coordinates within the view if the view itself has non-integral coordinates, then you'll observe antialiasing again.

Answer (score 2):

It's antialiasing. I can prevent this phenomenon by using your exact same code but drawing in a CGContext in which we have first called `CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing(context, false)`. Here it is *without* that call:

[image]

And here it is *with* that call:

[image]

But, as others have said, we can get the same result by changing your 33.7 and 33.5 to 40, so that we come down on pixel boundaries.

Comment: In situations where antialiasing is necessary, is there another solution? I've also had this problem with diagonal lines and arcs.

Comment: Create the rectangles 0.5 pixels larger than they should be so that they line up on the pixel rather than in between

Comment: ... though a better solution would surely be to round vertical extents to pixel boundaries, retaining anti-aliasing on the vertical edges?

Comment: Sorry, now you're just leeching. I have explained the phenomenon and shown how to "prevent" it. My work here on Earth is done!

Comment: How could this be solved with two triangles with adjacent, touching and diagonal edges?

Comment: @DefinitelyNotAPlesiosaur overlapping them may be your best option. You could also draw them without antialiasing but into a 2x larger context, and then scale it down. Might work, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely happening because the rectangle coordinates you are using to draw shapes are fractional values. As a result Core Graphics performs antialiasing at the edges of those rectangles when your coordinates land between pixel boundaries.

You could solve this by simply rounding the coordinates of the rectangles before drawing. You can use the `CGRectIntegral` function which performs this kind of rounding, for example:

```
CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectIntegral(rect1))
```

Comment: Okay, I withdraw my comment!

Comment: Cool! I like your answer by the way, I've learnt from it and could see myself using it.

Comment: And I modified my answer to acknowledge integrality as another solution. Together we have enough solutions to satisfy anyone! :)