# iOS Custom button title is blurry

Tags: ios, button, title, blurry

If I create a button in IB, and set only the type to be Custom, the Title and font size, it comes out nice and clear.  If I create it programmatically, then the font comes out fuzzy.  The code to create the button is:

CGRect frame = self.sendButton.frame;

```
    NSString *title = @"Read Disclosure";
    UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0];
    CGSize titleSize = [title sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:frame.size];

    CGFloat xValue = (self.view.frame.size.width - titleSize.width) / 2;
    CGFloat yValue = frame.origin.y - (titleSize.height / 2);

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];

    [button setFrame:CGRectMake(xValue, yValue, titleSize.width, titleSize.height * 2)];
    [button setTitle:@"Read Disclosure" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button.titleLabel setFont:font];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:79.0/255.0 blue:133.0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleShadowColor:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(disclosureButtonAction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [self.view addSubview:button];
```

I've tried every setting I can think of, and nothing seems to make a difference.  Any idea of what I'm missing here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You should make sure the `x`, `y`, `width`, and `height` of your frame are integers. You can do this manually with `round`/`floor`/`ceil`, or use [`CGRectIntegral`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectIntegral) if you don’t need that much manual control. Your button is falling on non-integer pixel boundaries, probably because of the floating point divide-by-2 in your code. This is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254657/uitextfield-blurred-text).

Be aware that `sizeWithFont:` may return non-integer floats as well.

Comment: yes, that is it.  i thought i had checked these out, but i guess not.  thanks!

Comment: thanks!  how do i mark it, with the "Was this post useful..." buttons below?