# UITextview is blurred when draw image

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, drawimage, cgimage

When I draw a new image, uitextview is blurred.

First text which is after draw new image. it looks like fuzzy.

Seconde text is captured

[image]

I tried this anwser changing frame to integer.

[UITextField blurred text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254657/uitextfield-blurred-text)

It was working before draw new image but it doesn't work when draw image.

here is my code

```
// UIView -> UIImage
convenience init(view: UIView) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.isOpaque, 0)
    view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    
    self.init(cgImage: image.cgImage!)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the priority of the textview to a higher value than the usual value.

Comment: it mean 'constraint priority"?

Comment: yess. its constraint priority. Let me know if this works

Comment: sorry,I don't understand how to set prioiry textview like width, height or something like that??

Answer (score 0):

Im usually specify scale value for *UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions*

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
```

But 0 should also work. In Apple docs written to use 0.0 as scale value to use device scale value (like I set manually) - maybe in current place 0 is not the same zero like 0.0? :)

Comment: thank you for your answer! I changed sacle to uiscreen main scale. but, it's not working :(